# Why is my settings.json code not working in meteor

Tags: meteor

So im really new to meteor, and im trying to deploy my app. So I created a settings.json file and put this code in it:

```
"galaxy.meteor.com": {
"env": {
    "ROOT_URL": "http://<myapp>.meteorapp.com/",
    "DEPLOY_HOSTNAME":"galaxy.meteor.com"
    "MONGO_URL":"mongodb+srv://abidmir:<password>@cluster0.6fk1x.mongodb.net/Meteor? 
    retryWrites=true&w=majority"
      }
 }
```

but every time i try to deploy it using:

```
DEPLOY_HOSTNAME=galaxy.meteor.com meteor deploy <myapp>.meteorrapp.com --settings 
settings.json
```

I get this message:

```
Errors prevented deploying:
While preparing to deploy:                    
settings.json: parse error reading settings file
```

what am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe `metoerapp` in your DEPLOY_HOSTNAME var? (spelling)?

Comment: yea that wasnt it. just tried it and it still gave the same error

Answer (score 3):

This JSON is not valid. A comma is missing after `"galaxy.meteor.com"`, and the whole code needs to be enclosed in curly braces:

```
{
    "galaxy.meteor.com": {
        "env": {
            "ROOT_URL": "http://<myapp>.meteorapp.com/",
            "DEPLOY_HOSTNAME": "galaxy.meteor.com",
            "MONGO_URL": "mongodb+srv://abidmir:<password>@cluster0.6fk1x.mongodb.net/Meteor?retryWrites = true & w = majority "
        }
    }
}
```